# setcookies and header send

Tags: php, headers, cookies

I put simple php condition in the `header.php` of template as this :

```
setcookie("test_time_".$cookie_id."", $cookies_times, time()+3600);
```

The result always as this **headers already sent**, I use this inside plugin and also I try outside the plugin and the result always the same.

It´s possible use cookies in header or what can i do for fix this problem , I need use cookies for works little function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have appears because you set your cookies too late. You have to set it before anything will be rendered. Set your cookies in the `your-plugin-file.php` file.

Also you can check if headers were sent or not by calling `headers_sent()` function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_init' );
function wpse8170_init() {
    if ( !headers_sent() ) {
        setcookie("test_time_".$cookie_id."", $cookies_times, time()+3600);
    }
}
```

Comment: The probem i use plugin and i don´t know how i can do this , how i can include this from plugin in header ? , thak´s

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it now

Comment: If you think that the answer is correct, then mark it as it is.

Comment: Yes , one thing more please , if i have for example one file in my plugin called code.php how i can insert in header this file from plugin it´s my last question , thank´s regards !!!

Comment: You shouldn't insert it into the header. Just add the snippet into your `code.php` file and it will add a cookie for you.

Comment: Yes but if activate my plugin and my plugin have 2 files and one file it´s for options inside plugin backend and other and this have cookies it´s for load inside website how i can do for load in the head or other site of template the plugin becaus ei have 2 files, this it´s my dude , thank´s for your help

Comment: You shouldn't add functionality to Wordpress with a pile of file includes, you should use actions and filters https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API